# php preg_match -> save matched value in variable?

Tags: php, preg-match

my `$content` variable stores a youtube video link.

```
$youtubeurl = "/(\[TRACK=)((http|https)(\:\/\/)(www|it|co\.uk|ie|br|pl|jp|fr|es|nl|de)(\.youtube\.)(com|it|co\.uk|ie|br|pl|jp|fr|es|nl|de)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\/\?_=&;]*))(\])/si"; 


$video = preg_match($youtubeurl, $content , $found);
print_r($video); // 1
```

How can I store the value of the matched string in a variable? Now if I `print_r($video)` I'm just getting printed a `1` which means it's found. However i need to hold the found string in a variable. How can i do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should find it in `$found[2]`

That contains all the captured matches, which is all the patterns you've got in parentheses.

- $found[0] = entire match
- $found[1] = 1st expression [TRACK=
- $found[2] = entire URL, which you have a number of sub-groups in - these will form following captured matches:
- $found[3] = http or https
- $found[4] = separator ://
- $found[5] = subdomain
- $found[5] = .youtube.
- $found[6] = top level domain
- $found[7] = path
- $found[8]= closing ]

Clearly, you're using parentheses in a fairly wasteful way, as you're capturing data you have no intention of using. You can use `(?: )` as a way of grouping a pattern without capturing, e.g. `(?:http|https)` matches http or https, but doesn't capture it.

Answer (score 1):

use [`preg_filter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-filter.php) - if you want to use it with multiple links (will return only correct).

or use [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), to take what you need from `$content`.

Comment: how can i use preg_replace in order to store the found string in a variable? I don't need to replace anything. i just want to see if text is matching my pattern and if so store this matched string inside of a variable!

Comment: preg_replace( "/foo (bar)/", "\$1", "foo bar foo bar" ); will return "bar bar";